# How to authenticate from a token in a URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I need to create a website with non standard authorizaion logic (or rather not exactly the site. It should be separate Area in existing ASP.NET MVC3 application). Access to most of the pages sould be available only to authorized users. Authorization is carried out on the token passed in the link. After the user arrived to this area, the token should be checked and if it’s valid site will create a session key for 30 minutes (we already have our own mechanisms of session managment and it should be used).

Workflow example :
Third-party website generates a link for user, e.g. https://example.com/securedPage/?accountId=123456&token=XXXXX
Our site check this token (it depends on the page from URL, in this case https://example.com/securedPage/)
If the token is valid, example.com obtains a session key for the user and stores it in cookies.
Then user continues browsing whole website and only session is checked.

I’m new to MVC framework, so I’d like to ask several questions about architecture. 
What is an apropriate place for this logic? ActionInvoker, Global.asax etc.?
Currently I'm trying to create my own ActionInvoker and keep this logic there, but I'm afraid that it could be a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want yo extend the Action of the controller to inject/check your token.

[I think the global action filters should help you](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx).

Comment: I'm wondering if you could tell me the way of how to implement this on MVC2 framework, without filters. Can I extend standard authentification mechanism for my needs?

Comment: With MVC2 I think of implementing something similar in a controller base and then let all your controllers to use some functions inside the base one to check if authentication is valid. Or extend the action. try look at this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695917.aspx